# \linebreak after a scope

Tags: typography

I can insert many empty lines using `\linebreak` after a text:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
text1
\linebreak
\linebreak
\linebreak
text2
\end{document}
```

However, if the first part of the text is inserted into some kine of a scope (e.g. `center`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
  text1\linebreak
\end{center}
\linebreak
\linebreak
text2
\end{document}
```

there is an error:

```
! LaTeX Error: There's no line here to end.
```

How to approach this problem?

Comment: Using `\linebreak` to leave blank lines is wrong to begin with.

Comment: Center and linebreak really do not make sense, used together. Unlike \\, the \linebreak` command justifies the line that it has just broken. But that does not make sense while centering. Use \\ instead. Admittedly the error message is confusing; LaTeX could just as easily have automatically substituted the effect of \\ there. And, as @egreg just noted, \linebreak is not intended for blank lines. (edited in response to @egreg comment)

Comment: What is the end-goal here?

Comment: @egreg - that is why I asked more subtly - how to approach this problem?

Comment: @Werner, the end goal is to insert 1, 2, 3, etc. empty lines after a block of text.

Comment: @Viesturs: Then use `\par\vspace{3\baselineskip}`.

Comment: @Werner. Thanks! What is the meaning of `\par`?

Comment: @Viesturs -- `\par` ends the current paragraph, and triggers its formatting.  (a blank line is the equivalent of `\par`.)  quite a few attributes of a text are not resolved until a paragraph is terminated: applying the proper baselines is one of the most noticeable; if `\large` is applied to the paragraph text, and the text is ended without an explicit termination to the paragraph, the baselines will not be the correct distance apart, usually too close together.